# Better way to create block matrices out of individual blocks in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the code

```
M=5;N=3;
A11=np.random.rand(M,M);
A12=np.random.rand(M,N);
A21=np.random.rand(N,M);
A22=np.random.rand(N,N);
```

I am new to numpy and learning it. I want to create a block matrix in the following manner

```
RowBlock1=np.concatenate((A11,A12),axis=1)
RowBlock2=np.concatenate((A21,A22),axis=1)
Block=np.concatenate((RowBlock1,RowBlock2),axis=0)
```

Is there a more easy way to do it? For eg:, in matlab I would do

```
Block=[[A11,A12];[A21,A22]]
```

and will be done with it.I understand that this is reserved only for arrays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of NumPy 1.13, there's [`numpy.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html):

```
Block = numpy.block([[A11, A12], [A21, A22]])
```

For previous versions, there's [`bmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html):

```
Block = numpy.bmat([[A11, A12], [A21, A22]])
```

`numpy.bmat` creates a matrix, rather than an array. This is usually a bad thing. You can call `asarray` on the result if you want an array, or use the [`A` attribute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html):

```
Block = numpy.bmat([[A11, A12], [A21, A22]]).A
```

`bmat` also does some messing around with stack frames to let you do this:

```
Block = numpy.bmat('A11,A12; A21,A22')
```

Comment: and if you want to do it with sparse matrices, i.e., `A11`,...,`A22` are `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` types, then you can use `scipy.sparse.bmat([[A11,A12],[A21,A22]])` or selectively replace `Aii` with `None` if you want that section to be zeros