# Arranging numpy arrays in a block matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 numpy arrays `A`, `B` and `C`. For simplicity, let's assume that they are all of shape `[n, n]`. I want to arrange them as a block matrix

```
A    B
B^t  C
```

where `B^t` shall denote the transpose of `B`. Of course, I could do this via a series of concatenations

```
top_row = np.concatenate([A, B], axis=1)
bottom_row = np.concatenate([B.transpose(), C], axis=1)
result = np.concatenate([top_row, bottom_row], axis=0)
```

Is there a simpler, more readable way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to create block matrices out of individual blocks in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469692/better-way-to-create-block-matrices-out-of-individual-blocks-in-numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of NumPy 1.13, there's [`np.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html). This builds matrices out of nested lists of blocks, but it's also more general, handling higher-dimensional arrays and certain not-quite-grid cases. It also produces an ndarray, unlike `bmat`.

```
np.block([[A, B], [B.T, C]])
```

---

For previous versions, you can use the NumPy built-in [`np.bmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html) that's perfectly suited for such a task, like so -

```
np.bmat([[A, B], [B.T, C]])
```

As mentioned in the [`comments by @unutbu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108335/arranging-numpy-arrays-in-a-block-matrix#comment63650530_38108383), please note that the output would be a NumPy matrix. If the intended output is an array instead, we need to convert it, like so -

```
np.asarray(np.bmat([[A, B], [B.T, C]]))
```

or

```
np.bmat([[A, B], [B.T, C]]).A
```

Comment: Might be good to note `np.bmat` returns a `matrix`, not an `array`. `np.asarray` could  be used to convert the matrix to an array.

Comment: @unutbu Ah yes! Let me add that info.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow overlooked ``np.bmat``. I was thinking about using numpy matrices for my problem, anyway.

Comment: @lballes Ah so no conversion needed then, awesome!

Comment: Might be a useful piece of information for someone else, anyway.

Comment: Internally `bmat` is doing the same 3 `concatenate` actions.

Answer (score 0):

Stripped of some bells and whisles, `np.bmat` does this:

```
def foo(alist):
    rowlist=[]
    for row in alist:
        rowlist.append(np.concatenate(row,axis=1))
    return np.concatenate(rowlist, axis=0)
```

So for example:

```
In [1026]: A=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2);B=np.arange(2).reshape(2,1);C=np.array([0]).reshape(1,1)

In [1027]: foo([[A,B],[B.T,C]])
Out[1027]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Making the inputs matrices simplifies the `reshape` preparation.